# Date input not working in firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, datepicker

I have the following date input:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="start_date">Start Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="start_date" id="start_date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
</div>
```

If I click on it in chrome, a date picker pops up:

[image: datepicker in chrome]

However, if I click it in firefox, the datepicker does not pop [image: datepicker in firefox]up:

Does anyone know why this is happening and/or how I can fix it in firefox so it is consistent?

Note - I am using bootstrap 3

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It is now supported in Firefox as of version 57, released 14th Nov 2017

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT** as others have mentioned

> input type="date" is now supported in FireFox

Unfortunately `<input type="date"/>` is not supported in firefox. To be able to use date type in all browser you can check using modernizer and if not supported you can fall back to use javascript to show the datepickerr.

```
<script>
    $(function(){           
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
            $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                  dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
                }
             );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How can I use this? I'm new to javascript. I've added the Modernizr file to my project. Then at the top of my html file i've pointed to the js code (e.g. <script src="modernizr-custom.js">). I've then put the script you provided right under the src call. However, I'm still not getting a datepicker in Firefox.

Comment: Note: `input type="date"` is now supported in FireFox

Answer (score 2):

**Just Update FireFox to latest** (v57) this painful issue is gone forever :-)

**See** [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=date)
[image]

**Docs**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

**Proof**:

[image]

Comment: except it only works by clicking on the icon

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of why the format not working the same on all browsers is due to the different implementation of the javascript Date() constructor on different browsers:

```
alert (new Date ('30/12/2017')) ->
```

Firefox:

> "Invalid Date"

(that may be correct depending on definition).

IE:

> "Wed Jun 12 2019..."

(now that is wrong!)

.. this comes from C/C++ internal: it is converting 30 to 2 years (24 months) + 6 months -> Jun (Dec + 6 months) 2019 (2017 + 2 years).

Basically, it's working badly on ALL browsers!

You can change (or override date function) "jquery.validate.js":

Here is the fix. This works for a client of mine:

You will also notice that for IE and so on, it does more checking by not allowing many bad dates.

`// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date`

date: function (value, element) {

```
// test
// alert (new Date('30/12/2017'))

// original - bad
// return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value).toString());

// fix
var oInst = $.datepicker._getInst(element)
var sDateFormat = $.datepicker._get(oInst, "dateFormat")
var oSettings = $.datepicker._getFormatConfig(oInst)
var dtDate = null
try {
    dtDate = $.datepicker.parseDate(sDateFormat, value, oSettings)
} catch (ex) { }

return this.optional(element) || dtDate != null
```

},

Cheers, Ron Lentjes, LC CLS