# Bootstrap Datepicker not working in Firefox by works in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in use on a web app. It works fine in all browsers except FF. Interestingly there are no JS errors in FF, but what I do notice is my input field is turned from `type=text` to `type=date`, no calendar popup works, and the date format I place in it is ignored.

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="date-picker form-control" name="expense_date_editable" id="expense_date">
```

In FF Inspect it appears as:

```
<input type="date" class="date-picker form-control" name="expense_date_editable" id="expense_date">
```

My init JS for the datepicker:

```
$('#expense_date').datepicker({
    orientation: "bottom auto",
    clearBtn: true,
    todayBtn: true,
    autoClose: true
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    // do stuff...
}).on('clearDate', function(e) {
    // reset date
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look here, it looks like the same issue : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37309128/2159528

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette no, this is not the same issue. 
TheRealPapa did you ever find a solution to this?