# Can Input in only one input field in my HTML Form

Tags: html, css

I've created an HTML form in which I can add date and attendance. I've used a table to implement it. The code works fine in Google Chrome but in any other browser, I can only add a date on the first date field. If I click on other date fields even then, the first date field is selected.
Here is my code. Where is the problem?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Attendance</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="date" name="date4" id="date4"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="atd4" id="atd4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="date" name="date5" id="date5"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="atd5" id="atd5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="date" name="date6" id="date6"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="atd6" id="atd6"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="date" name="date7" id="date7"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="atd7" id="atd7"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="date" name="date8" id="date8"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="atd8" id="atd8"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/xbwn6age/ !?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Which browsers are you testing?

Comment: Firefox doesn't support HTML5's <input type="date"/>

Comment: Old browser doesnot support <input type="date"/> . Use datepicker jquery  instead .

Comment: @J.Shabu thats what I am saying !!

Answer (score 1):

**Without script** 
input elements with type="date" do not show as any date field/calendar in Firefox or in IE 11 and earlier versions.

**Here is a fix with scripts**

[Click here for the working code](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/createelementcheck2.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Only following browser versions will support `date` and `time` input type

[image]

Please refer [**input date time**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

The `date` picker isn't supported by all browsers.
[See this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)

You can refer to this link for a workaround:
[Date input not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308953/date-input-not-working-in-firefox)