# How to use form::date in laravel to work on all browsers

Tags: laravel, firefox, laravelcollective

I try to work with {{Form::date()}} in laravel which will work just fine in `chrome` but not in `firefox`

here is firefox view:

[image: firefox]

And this is chrome view
[image: chrome]

> What I want is to view in Firefox browser be like chrome view, and for
>   the reason that I don't understand when I try to save in Firefox i get
>   this error:

[image: error]

But in chrome will save my data with no problem.

Here is my blade code to collect data:

```
{{ Form::label('valid_from', 'Valid From') }}
{{ Form::date('valid_from', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Comment: This looks like a date format issue. Chrome supports html5's new <input type="date"> which declares how the date is transfered to the server, but firefox doesn't and send whatever you've written as-is. Try inputting the value in the format "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: @sisve how i do that?

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308953/date-input-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

OK, here is how I solved it.

I used [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and changed my input field to something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  {{ Form::label('valid_from', 'Valid From') }}
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
      <input type='text' name="valid_from" id="valid_from" class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I added JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
          viewMode: 'years',
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
    });
</script>
```

And instead of writing the date manually, I get it from nice and beautiful drop-box and now I can save my data no matter what browser I use.

Hope this helps others.