# my datapicker code is not working in firefox

Tags: php, html

My date picker code is working in chrome but not working in mozilla firefox. How i can fix the issue?

I have called a function and and described date picker in the modal box, how can I make it work properly in both chrome and in firefox.

My code is here:(at view in mvc controller)

```
<input class='form-control' type='date' id='joining_date' name='status'></form></div>
```

Comment: Please show how your date picker is implemented to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately  is not supported in firefox. To be able to use date type in all browser you can check using modernizer and if not supported you can fall back to use javascript to show the datepickerr.

```
<script>
    $(function(){           
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
            $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                  dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
                }
             );
        }
    });
</script>
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308953/date-input-not-working-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work on Firefox unfortunately, and there's no good/easy reference to remember which html/css features work/don't work on which browsers, it will just take practice.

Fortunately, there are a lot of options for datepickers out there. This guy has a simple one:

[image]

http://chrishulbert.github.io/datepicker/